# How do I loop pulling in all the folders in a directory, run the same code on them and get summary output files?

Tags: r, function, file

I have a directory with a folder for each individual patient on a study, but multiple files within each folder for that patient. I want to run the same code in R for each folder and create a summary file.

so for example:

```
setwd("~/pt1")

##pull in files
T1<-read.csv('T1.csv')
T2<-read.csv('T2.csv')
T3<-read.csv('T3.csv')
T4<-read.csv('T4.csv')

## lots of code here ##

--> outputsummaryfile
```

Repeat for 80 more folders(patients).

I know how to create a function and pull in and run multiple files, but I'm stuck on how to pull in multiple folders and run a function on multiple files within that folder.

Any help?

Comment: I suggest you read about [lists of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227).

Answer (score 0):

The following is an quick way for limited files.

```
all_files_list<-list.files('path to folder',full.names = TRUE,recursive=TRUE,include.dirs=TRUE) # this will now be a list of all files with full paths.

main_df<- data.frame() # your main dataframe
for(file in all_files_list){ # loops the file listing
  tmp_df <- read_tsv(file) #reads each file
  #process tmp_df 
  main_df<- bind_rows(tmp_df) # merge to main dataframe provided same set of columns
}
```

Note that since **all_files_list** is a list and if it will contain large number of files, you can user **purrr** package to streamline it.

Update1:

Another option is to use purrr package and read all files into a list of dataframes as follows:

```
list_of_dataframes<-purrr::map(all_files_list,read_csv,id="filename") #ID column will have the filenames.
```

Then you could loop your **all_files_list** and process each dataframe as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about `purrr::map`. This video also shows its use (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzUmK0Y07ck&t=1598s) and there is an example about reading multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can list directories with `list.dirs`, then loop the dir's

```
dirs <- list.dirs(path = "[...]", recursive = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(dirs)) {
  files <- list.files(path = "[...]")
  do.the.magic.on(files[i])
}
```